# GET from another page and POST on the current page

Tags: php, mysql

I am creating a script and I came across a problem. I am having to use $_POST and $_GET on the same page, which I don't think makes sense.

I get the value for user id using the GET method from another page through a link and I have to input data from a form into the database in the current page.

CODE SNIPPET 1 : (GET METHOD on page page.php)

```
echo "<td align=center width=90px height=10px><strong><a href='sessions.php?id=".$userid."' style=text-decoration:none><font color='red' size='5pt'>$i</font></a></strong></td>";
```

CODE SNIPPET 2 : (POST METHOD on sessions.php going to same page sessions.php)

```
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]=="GET"){
                    $id=$_GET["id"];
                    if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]=="POST")
                    $suggestions=$_POST["suggest"];
```

Can I get the userid from the url and the POST the values from the form in the same page?
If not, is there a way I can do this better?

Comment: do you have a form in the second page where you want to POST I mean do you have a form in sessions.php ??

Comment: Nope. I have one form in session.php and it is  inserted to database in the same page.

Comment: Careful: It's not going to be GET and POST at the same time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use one hidden input field in your form in session.php and store $_GET['id'] in value attribute of that input field and it will be pass with your form submit to session.php `<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $_GET['id']">`

Comment: without the name attribute in the input section how the data will be posted??

Answer (score 0):

you can get the value from GET by adding the following code in sesssion.php

```
$id="";    
if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
        $id=$_GET['id'];
    }else{
       $id="";
    }
```

then in the form located at session.php place a input field like following

```
<input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $_GET['id']" name="suggest">
```

then add the following code in the same page

```
    if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]=="POST"){
          if($id){
         $suggestions=$_POST["suggest"];
       // run your sql query for insert.
    }

 }
```